# monolog configuration in symfony and customization

Tags: php, symfony, logging, monolog, symfony-2.6

I am working on a web app built using Symfony 2.6 and there are different configuration inside `app/config` folder. How do I know which one is being used.
Inside `app/config` I see `config.yml` `config_dev.yml` `config_prod.yml` and the `monolog` entry I see in `config_dev.yml` and also in `monolog_prod.yml`. It is as below.

```
monolog:
handlers:
    main:
        type:         fingers_crossed
        action_level: error
        handler:      nested
    nested:
        type:  stream
        path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
        level: debug
    console:
        type:  console
```

Now I want to use monolog to input some logs in a controller and put those logs separate form other logs. How can this be done?.

Answer (score 0):

You know which one is used on your environment.
If you are in dev mode you are using `config_dev.yml` merged with `config.yml`
You can check it into your virtual host if the file is on `app.php` you are in `prod` mode, if the file points to `app_dev.php` you are in `dev` mode usually

To log into other files you can create a channel like this:

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
        your_handler:
            level:    debug
            type:     stream
            path:     '%kernel.logs_dir%/custom.log'
            channels: ['your_channel']
        nested:
            type:  stream
            path:  "%kernel.logs_dir%/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
        console:
            type:  console
```

And into your controller you can call it in this way:

```
$logger = $this->get('monolog.logger.your_handler');
$logger->debug('your custom message into your custom log file');
```